# pd.to_datetime is getting half my dates with flipped day / months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My dataset has dates in the European format, and I'm struggling to convert it into the correct format before I pass it through a pd.to_datetime, so for all day < 12, my month and day switch.
Is there an easy solution to this?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_csv(loc,dayfirst=True)
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Is there a way to force datetime to acknowledge that the input is formatted at dd/mm/yy?

Thanks for the help!

Edit, a sample from my dates:

```
renewal["Date"].head()
Out[235]: 
0    31/03/2018
2    30/04/2018
3    28/02/2018
4    30/04/2018
5    31/03/2018
Name: Earliest renewal date, dtype: object
```

After running the following:

```
renewal['Date']=pd.to_datetime(renewal['Date'],dayfirst=True)
```

I get:

```
Out[241]: 
0    2018-03-31  #Correct
2    2018-04-01   #<-- this number is wrong and should be 01-04 instad
3    2018-02-28   #Correct
```

Comment: try adding `dayfirst=True` to your `to_datetime`, i.e. `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=true)`.

Comment: @Stev I already have that in there, it doesn't seem to be stopping the problem

Comment: You have put it in the read_csv, according to the code above.

Comment: Sorry - misread your comment, although this didn't seem to work either. I think the best solution may be to just update my database

Comment: Can you update your post to show a couple of line of your input file? This should be simple to solve. Feel free to edit it but please leave the date in the true format.

Comment: '30/04/2018' is becoming '2018-04-01'? Are you sure?

Comment: @Stev No, I just sorted it differently to include a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the date construction directly if you define separate columns for 'year', 'month' and 'day', like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': ['01/03/2018', '06/08/2018', '31/03/2018', '30/04/2018']}
)
date_parts = df['Date'].apply(lambda d: pd.Series(int(n) for n in d.split('/')))
date_parts.columns = ['day', 'month', 'year']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_parts)

date_parts
#    day  month  year
# 0    1      3  2018
# 1    6      8  2018
# 2   31      3  2018
# 3   30      4  2018

df
#         Date
# 0 2018-03-01
# 1 2018-08-06
# 2 2018-03-31
# 3 2018-04-30
```